# DRY in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to improve my code in controller according to DRY.

```
  def create
    blog.user = current_user
    blog.save
    respond_with blog, location: user_root_path
  end

  def update
    blog.update(blog_params)
    respond_with blog, location: user_root_path
  end

  def destroy
    blog.destroy
    respond_with blog, location: user_root_path
  end
```

Every method has a respond_with blog, location: user_root_path. How can I hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `:after_action` filter

After filters are run after the action completes. It can modify the response. Most of the time if something is done in an after filter, it can be done in the action itself, but if there is some logic to be run after running any of a set of actions, then an after filter is a good place to do it.

```
:after_action :responding, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]

def create
  blog.user = current_user
  blog.save
end

def update
  blog.update(blog_params)
end

def destroy
  blog.destroy
end

def :responding
  respond_with blog, location: user_root_path
end
```